# Using for loops to identify rows

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145195/excel-vba-row-highlighting), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568038/identifying-and-highlighting-a-blank-row-in-excel-vba), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729788/excel-vba-highlighting-entire-row).

I'm trying to highlight a row based on the string contents of a cell in the first column.

For example, if a cell in the first column contains the string "Total", then highlight the row a darker color.

```vb
Sub tryrow()
    Dim Years
    Dim rownum As String
    
    Years = Array("2007", "2008", "2009") ' short example 
    For i = 0 To UBound(Years)
        Set rownum = Range("A:A").Find(Years(i) & " Total", LookIn:=xlValues).Address
        Range(rownum, Range(rownum).End(xlToRight)).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

I get this error message:

> Compile error: Object required

The editor highlights `rownum =` , as if this object hadn't been initialized with `Dim rownum As String`.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use conditional formatting?

Comment: and then if no matches are found, you will get another error here `Range("A:A").Find(Years(i) & " Total", LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: Since no one has said it, the error is because you're trying to `Set` a string, which is invalid syntax in VBA - you only `Set` ranges or objects, you can just give a string a value with `mystring = "my string value"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple issues here, indicated below alongside the fix:

```
Sub tryrow()
    Dim Years() As String 'Best practice is to dim all variables with types. This makes catching errors early much easier
    Dim rownum As Range 'Find function returns a range, not a string

    Years = Array("2007", "2008", "2009") ' short example
    For i = 0 To UBound(Years)
        Set rownum = Range("A:A").Find(Years(i) & " Total", LookIn:=xlValues) 'Return the actual range, not just the address of the range (which is a string)
        If Not rownum Is Nothing Then 'Make sure an actual value was found
            rownum.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'Instead of trying to build row range, just use the built-in EntireRow function. Also, ColorIndex for gray is 15 (1 is black, which makes it unreadable)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: A-ha! Thank you so much, what a big help!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid loop by using autofilter which will work much faster. The code assumes that table starts from A1 cell:

```
Sub HighlightRows()

    Dim rng As Range, rngData As Range, rngVisible As Range
    '//All table
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    '//Table without header
    With rng
        Set rngData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*Total*"
    '// Need error handling 'cause if there are no values, error will occur
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVisible = rngData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Err = 0 Then
        rngVisible.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```